# Does mesirah apply to the secular state of Israel

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, modern-times, state-of-israel, mesirah

The Halacha of mesirah prohibits Jews turning fellow Jews  over to non Jewish governments and law enforcement. However, does it prohibit turning fellow Jews to the secular state of israel, which is run by Jews but not governed by Beit dins?

Comment: The Aruch HaShulchan wrote that *mesirah* didn't apply to a government like the United Kingdom of the early 1900s...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R. Yubhal Cherlow [writes](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8/):

> העברת מידע לרשויות מדינת ישראל על עבירות שנעשות בתחומה אינה קשורה
> לדיני "מוסר". שלטון מדינת ישראל אינו שלטון זר, אלא שהוא שליח שלנו
> עצמנו, ונבחר על ידינו, ויש לקיים את החוקים, ואם החוקים מחייבים למסור
> מידע (כמו פגיעה בילדים בתוך המשפחה) - זו לא מסירה אלא דבר נכון לעשותו.
>
> Transferring information to the authorities of the State of Israel
> about crimes committed in its domain is not related to "moser" laws.
> The government of the State of Israel is not a foreign government,
> rather it is our own emissary, and was chosen by us, and its laws must
> be followed, and if the laws require us to provide information (such
> as concerning the harming of children within the family) - this is not
> *mesirah* but rather the right thing to do.

This is of course just one approach. I would expect that among anti-Zionists you'll find a different answer.

Comment: U needn't nec be anti-zionist to quibble with this

Comment: Is this different for him from any democracy?

Comment: @Nahum agreed, though I think you are more likely to find an answer in the other direction from that camp.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think he would have used language as strong for a democracy that is not predominantly Jewish, but that's a fair question.